# Regex: Replace a number (or can be a word) in a particular line

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this number `2002` on multiple lines, from multiples files.

```
`On March 02, 2002, in Performance Management, by Michael London`
`On December 14, 2002, in Performance Management, by Michael London`
```

I want to replace `2002` with `2012` , as to become:

```
`On March 02, 2012, in Performance Management, by Michael London`
`On December 14, 2012, in Performance Management, by Michael London`
```

Comment: No need for regex for this. Simple find/replaces are most easily done via the UI as Toto notes below.

Answer (score 0):

FIND: `(^.*)(2002)(.*?)(Michael)(.*?)`

REPLACE BY: `\12012\3\4\5`

or

FIND: `(^.*)(?=(2002)).*?(in Performance Management)`

REPLACE BY:`\12012, \3\4`

Comment: Why not simply Find: `2002` ; Replace: `2012`

Comment: @Toto, yes, was simple. But in the files, I have a lot of `2002` and I don't wanna replace all. Just those that contain particular words. Did you think I struggled in vain to do regex?

Comment: What words must be present to do the replacement? `in Performance Management` or `Michael` or both? Are they allways after the year?

Comment: instead of number, can be a world. And in first case must be `2002` before `Michael`, anywhere in the line. Second case, `2002` must be right in front of `in Performance Management`.

Comment: Find and Replace can still do this. Find "2002 Michael" and replace with "2012 Michael", or whichever you wish.

Comment: don't think so...  https://snipboard.io/Lrx23q.jpg